# Is it possible to retrieve "Contact Presence" from Microsoft Graph?

Tags: java, rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api, ucwa

I've been looking through the microsoft graph api: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview

So far i havent run into any issues using the api (Getting authentication code, getting users etc). But i can't seem to find their presence...

I have a list of "User" object, and i'd love to be able to add their presence..

Is this possible?

Comment: Afaik, i should also be able to retrieve this data through office 365 - but i dont know if that is better than the ucwa api. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Presence is not yet available in the Microsoft Graph. You can request it on UserVoice [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use one of the Skype APIs to get presence information.
https://dev.office.com/Skype/sdks#skypeWebSDK

Comment: It doesnt matter which of the apis i use? Do you by any chance know if its possible to receive presence from a specific email or?

Comment: Figured it would be best for me to use the UCWA API since it is rest. Is that possible with the enterprise application that i have created in Microsoft azure? The examples with UCWA all seem to be with specific user login, which is not what im looking for..

Comment: @matn, I'm not familiar enough with the Skype APIs to provide guidance on them. I did update your post with the Skype tag so hopefully someone else can provide that guidance.

Comment: Thank you Michael, i hope someone will provide me with some guidance. Thank you for your help.